# Group by fixed interval range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, relational-database

I have time stored in unix format `int`. I want to group the result by the intervals of 1day i.e 86400 seconds.

sample data

```
timestamp  | state
+++++++++++++++++++
1540427604 | ABC
1540770300 | PQR
1540770050 | PQR
1540751300 | ABC
```

I want to group the count of `state` by period of each 86400, i.e if someone asked from 1540425600 (i.e 25 OCT 2018) to 1540771200 (i.e 29 OCT 2018), then output should be

```
range                    | state  | count
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1540425600 - 1540512000  |   ABC  | 1
1540684800 - 1540771200  |   ABC  | 1
1540684800 - 1540771200  |   PQR  | 2
```

I've tried this so many things but this one is what I think more close to..

```
select 
    concat(86400*floor(timestamp /86400), '-', 86400*floor(timestamp/86400) + 86400) as `range` , count(state)
    from MT 
    where timestamp between MINDATE AND MAXDATE
    group by `range` order by `range`;
```

But the output I'm getting is not starting with the MINDATE passed or in multiple of MINDATE... but it is in range of 86400. I want the range should always start with mMINDATE if such record exists OR in muliple of MINDATE * 86400

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here does the job:

```
select
concat(min(floor(timestamp / 86400) * 86400), ' - ', max(floor(timestamp / 86400) * 86400) + 86400) as `range`
, state
, count(*)
from t
group by floor(timestamp / 86400), state
order by `range`
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2be5de/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, but the result should be... range must start with MINDATE provided by user or in multiple of MINDATE*86400, currently, your statrs with min(timestamp) which is not equal to MINDATE nor in multiple of MINDATE*86400

Comment: see sample required output I already provided in question. :(

Comment: Edited my answer. I think I've got it now, but your desired result has an error. The min range value for PQR should be 1540771200 because 1540770050 is smaller than 1540770300.

Comment: I already modified that error in my question. Thanks man, it worked now. :)